# Requiring type constraints for concrete types when working with higher-kinded data types and Barbies

Tags: haskell, higher-kinded-types

Given the following data type:

```
data FormInputH f = FormInputH
  { formNameH :: f Text,
    formEmailH :: f Text,
    formAgeH :: f Int
  }
  deriving stock (Generic)
  deriving anyclass (ApplicativeB, ConstraintsB, FunctorB, TraversableB)
```

(`ApplicativeB` etc. come from [the barbies library](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/barbies))

I'd like to write an instance for the `FromForm` type class from [http-api-data](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/http-api-data-0.5.1/docs/Web-FormUrlEncoded.html#t:FromForm). It's relatively straightforward to write an instance directly for all `f` that have an `Applicative` instance:

```
instance (Applicative f) => FromForm (FormInputH f) where
  fromForm f = FormInputH
   <$> (pure <$> parseUnique "name" f)
   <*> (pure <$> parseUnique "email" f)
   <*> (pure <$> parseUnique "age" f)
```

What I'd like to achieve is an equivalent implementation that uses less duplication int he code. For that purpose, I created a value that defines the names of the fields in the form:

```
formFieldNames :: FormInputH (Const Text)
formFieldNames =
  FormInputH
    (Const "name")
    (Const "email")
    (Const "age")
```

so that I can write more generic code in the `FromForm` instance:

```
instance (Applicative f) => FromForm (FormInputH f) where
  fromForm f = btraverse (\(Const name) -> pure <$> parseUnique name f) formFieldNames
```

Which doesn't work because

```
    • Could not deduce (FromHttpApiData a)
        arising from a use of ‘parseUnique’
      from the context: Applicative f
        bound by the instance declaration at src/FormInput.hs:41:10-51
      Possible fix:
        add (FromHttpApiData a) to the context of
          a type expected by the context:
            forall a. Const Text a -> Either Text (f a)
```

Is it possible to fix that? I kinda feel it's not, mainly because the `forall a.` in the signature of `btraverse` seems to not allow this flexibility here.

I tried adding `AllBF` constraint, but that didn't help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `baddDicts` (from the class `ConstraintsH`).

The function argument of `btraverse` has type `forall a. f a -> e (g a)`, where `f a` is the type of each field. You need a `FromHttpApiData a` constraint, which can only come from `f`, and this is indeed possible by choosing `f` to be `Product (Dict FromHttpApiData) (Const Text)`, which you can obtain from `baddDicts` (provided each field of the record does implement `FromHttpApiData`).

```
instance Applicative f => FromForm (FormInputH f) where
  fromForm f = btraverse (\(Pair Dict (Const field)) -> pure <$> parseUnique field f)
    (baddDicts @_ @_ @FromHttpApiData formFieldNames)
```

Minimal compilable snippet:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DerivingStrategies, DeriveAnyClass, DeriveGeneric, TypeApplications, FlexibleInstances #-}

module M where

import GHC.Generics
import Barbies
import Data.Functor.Const
import Data.Functor.Product
import Data.Barbie.Constraints

type Text = String

data Form

class FromHttpApiData a where
  parseUnique :: Text -> Form -> Either Text a

instance FromHttpApiData Text
instance FromHttpApiData Int

class FromForm a where
  fromForm :: Form -> Either Text a

data FormInputH f = FormInputH
  { formNameH :: f Text,
    formEmailH :: f Text,
    formAgeH :: f Int
  }
  deriving stock (Generic)
  deriving anyclass (ApplicativeB, ConstraintsB, FunctorB, TraversableB)

formFieldNames :: FormInputH (Const Text)
formFieldNames = FormInputH
  (Const "name")
  (Const "email")
  (Const "age")

instance Applicative f => FromForm (FormInputH f) where
  fromForm f = btraverse (\(Pair Dict (Const field)) -> pure <$> parseUnique field f)
    (baddDicts @_ @_ @FromHttpApiData formFieldNames)
```